# Inserting extern HTML <table> code into a <div> of my index.html

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, insert

I have a table in another HTML, but I want to insert it on my index.html. But I have this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL.

This is where I want to insert the table:

```
<div class="row" id="contenedor">
    <div class="col-md-10 tab-content" id="miContenido">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="medicamentos">

        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="insumos">
            <p>Aquí va la tabla de <strong>insumos</strong>.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="implementos">
            <p>Aquí va la tabla de <strong>implementos</strong>.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contacto">
            <p>Aquí va el formulario de <strong>contacto</strong>.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <img src="img/ofertas.gif" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(#medicamentos).load('medicamentos.html #medicamentosExt');
    });
</script>
```

This is the table in the external html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="medicamentosExt">
           <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="example">
               <thead>
                <tr class="info">
                    <th class="text-primary">Producto</th>
                    <th class="text-primary">Drogas</th>
                    <th class="text-primary">Presentación</th>
                    <th class="text-primary">Laboratorio</th>
                    <th class="text-primary">Precio</th>
                </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tafirol 500 mg</td>
                    <td>Paracetamol</td>
                    <td>Comp x 100 - 500 mg</td>
                    <td>Genomma</td>
                    <td>$ 33,90</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tafirol Forte</td>
                    <td>Paracetamol</td>
                    <td>Comp x 50 - 650 mg</td>
                    <td>Genomma</td>
                    <td>$ 24,40</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tafirol 1 g</td>
                    <td>Paracetamol</td>
                    <td>Comp x 80 - 1 g</td>
                    <td>Genomma</td>
                    <td>$ 59,07</td>
                </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery selector has to be in quotes.

**Your code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(#medicamentos).load('medicamentos.html #medicamentosExt');
    });
```

**Fix:**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#medicamentos').load('medicamentos.html #medicamentosExt');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error....

Use quotes in selector unless and until your selectors are passed through variable